# Search a part of a file in another file

Tags: c, file-io

This is part of a C code. I need help to fix it.
This program checks if a file signature is in another file.
If it is, the function finds match then it returns `1` else it returns `0`.

The problem is that it always returns `0` even when it should return `1`.

This is the function I wrote:

```
int scanFile(char* file_name, FILE * virus_signature, long virus_size) //Scan the given file to see if he has the signature
{
FILE * file_for_scan = fopen(file_name, "rb");
char ch_temp, ch_temp2;
int i = 0;
fseek(virus_signature, 0, SEEK_SET);
while ((ch_temp = fgetc(file_for_scan)) != EOF)
{
    if ((ch_temp2=fgetc(virus_signature)) == ch_temp)
    {
        i++;
        if (i == virus_size)
        {
            fclose(file_for_scan);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        i = 0;
        fseek(virus_signature, 0, SEEK_SET);
    }

}
fclose(file_for_scan);
return 0;
}
```

Please help me fix my code.

Comment: Explain what's wrong with your code

Comment: What's your problem exactly?

Comment: The program isn't working good. It returns all the times 0 and not 1 when it should be returned.

Comment: `while (((result2=fread(virus_buffer,1,sizeof(char),virus))>0)&&flag==1)`, I think you need to remove the flag==1 from here, you need to change the logic here

Comment: you're massively overcomplicating this. why don't you just read whole files into memory then use `memmem()` (or a loop plus `memcmp()` if it's not available) to find the location of the needle?

Comment: What does `fseek(virus, 0, SEEK_SET);` do each time it is encountered in the loop? What does `fread` read each time?

Comment: I edited my code but still doesn't works

Answer (score 0):

That is much more complicated than it needs to be.  With a 64-bit binary, `mmap()` the file then use `memcmp()` to search its contents:

```
int fd = open( "/path/to/haystack/file", O_RDONLY );
struct stat sb;
fstat( fd, &sb );
char *haystack = mmap( NULL, sb.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0 );
close( fd );

// needleSize is how many bytes the "needle" is
size_t bytesToSearch = sb.st_size - needleSize;
char *found = NULL;
for( size_t ii = 0UL; ii < bytesToSearch; ii++ )
{
    if (!memcmp( haystack + ii, needle, needleSize )
    {
        found = haystack + ii;
        break;
    }
}
// if found is non-NULL, it points to where the needle is
```

I left off all error checking and `munmap()`'ing the haystack file after the search loop.

If you're limited to a 32-bit binary, to handle arbitrarily large files you need to do something more complicated, but nowhere near as complicated as the code you posted.  You can use rolling `mmap()` calls, for example, `munmap()`'ing data you've already searched through so you don't use too much memory for a 32-bit process.

Comment: Windows has `CreateFileMapping()`.  MS documentation:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx  Example:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849400/how-to-createfilemapping-in-c